# `$injector:modulerr` when Importing submodule in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower, angularjs-module

I am having some trouble importing my sub-module when using the AngularJS framework.

I have created the module and its dependencies, checked my import order and imported the js files in the index.html `<script>` tag.

When my server attempts to render my page I get a `$injector:modulerr`

The stack trace points at bower, however all my bower components are present.

I am unsure how to debug this issue.

I have the directory structure:

```
app.js
hmodule/
hmodule/helpermonkeys.js
hmodule/services/monkeymessageservice.js
hmodule/controllers/monkeycontroller.js
```

## /app.js:

```
var centroApp = angular.module("centroApp", ['ngRoute', ..., 'ngWebSocket', 'helpermonkeys'])
```

## /hmodule/hm.js

```
(function() {                                                                                                                                             
    'use strict';                                                                                                                                             
    angular.module('helpermonkeys', ['ngWebSocket', 'monkeyMessageService', 'monkeyController']);                                                    
})();
```

## /hmodule/services/monkeymessageservice.js

```
(function() {                                                                                                                                                 
    'use strict';                                                                                                                                             
    angular.module('helpermonkeys').factory('monkeyMessageService', ['ngWebSocket', monkeyMessageService]);                                                   

    function monkeyMessageService($websocket) {                                                                                                               
        var messageService = {                                                                                                                                
            connect: connect,                                                                                                                                 
            sendActuatorRequest: sendActuatorRequest,                                                                                                         
            sendDataRequest: sendDataRequest,                                                                                                                 
            sendCommandRequest: sendCommandRequest,                                                                                                           
            messages: []                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                     

        return messageService;   
        ...
})();
```

## /hmmodule/controllers/monekeycontroller.js

```
(function() {                                                                                                                                                 
    'use strict';                                                                                                                                             
    angular.module('helpermonkeys').controller('monkeyController', ['$scope', 'monkeyMessageService', monkeyController]); 
 ....
})();
```

## index.html

```
    <script src="/js/helpermonkeysmodule/helpermonkeys.js"></script>                                                                                          
    <script src="/js/helpermonkeysmodule/services/monkeymessageservice.js"></script>                                                                          
    <script src="/js/helpermonkeysmodule/controllers/monkeycontroller.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

## Stack Trace

```
Failed to instantiate module centroApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=h...)
    at https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
    at https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:292
    at q (https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:359)
    at g (https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:382)
    at https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:40:34
    at q (https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:359)
    at g (https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:382)
    at eb (https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:382)
    at c (https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:19)
    at Ic (https://localhost/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:21:332
```

## Error URL:

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=helpermonkeys&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.9%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DmonkeyMessageService%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.9%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DmonkeyMessageService%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A412%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A235%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A24%253A282)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A25%253A20%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A40%253A17%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A359)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A382)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A40%253A34%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A359)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fbower_components%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A39%253A382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:6:412%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:40:292%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:359)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:40:34%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:359)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:382)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:40:34%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:359)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:39:382
```

Thanks to @charlietfl for pointing out the offending file can be found in the URL, I am going to investigate my Messaging service.

Comment: Follow the stack trace in the angular url error links, it will tell you which module is the culprit.

Comment: The stack trace indicated there is a bower issue. I will update with stack trace, but its not very useful.

Comment: module name is in first line of error where you cut it off with `...` . Can also be cause by a syntax error

Comment: Looks like `monkeyMessageService` does not exist as a module in your application for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an issue with my `monkeymessageservice`. The question is a bit of  rubbish one, the issue is my inexperience :p.

For reference the URL returned by the Angularjs includes the offending module.